# Replacing old mechanical line voltage thermostat with Caleo from Casa Connect

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat

**------ Update ------**

*I followed the instructions from Casa: I made A1 go into the new thermostat and then out into the blacks of B1 and C1 (see my diagram of the old setup below). Then I connected A2 directly to the whites of B2 and C2. This DOES work—the thermostat did power on but the heaters were turning on and off every 3 seconds. I have since learned that CASA DOES NOT support fan-forced heaters :(*

*For anyone interested, I did find a smart line-voltage thermostat that does support fan-forced heater: https://getmysa.com/.*

**------------------**

My old thermostat provides electricity to two wall heaters with fans (I believe the heat and fans always run at the same time). I'd like to replace the thermostat with the [Wifi thermostat from Casa](https://casaconnect.com/caleo/?v=7516fd43adaa), which only has two wires, a line and load.

As you can see, the black and white wires coming into the old thermostat are both hot. Then they go out to two lines, B and C.

I don't understand what is going on after that. One wire coming out of the thermostat (D1) connects to the black wires of B and C and the other (D2) connects to the white wires of B and C.

**How do I wire the new wifi thermostat?**

[image: Diagram of old thermostat wiring]

Here is what the old thermostat looks like when I opened the back:

[image: old mechanical thermostat]

And here are some instructions from Casa, but I'm not sure they apply to my situation.

[image: instructions from Casa Connect for the Caleo thermostat]

Comment: Have you looked at the "4 wire install" instructions?

Comment: Yes, I looked at that. I thought about making A1 go into the new thermostat and then out into the blacks of B and C. Then I would connect A2 directly to the whites of B and C. But I'm still not sure.

Comment: Ok I just tried what I commented above. Oddly the thermostat came on but the heaters kept turning on and off every 3 seconds.

Comment: Curious...edit your question into that :) Hopefully someone can lick this mystery

Comment: Post your update as an answer and I'll give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions from Casa: I made A1 go into the new thermostat and then out into the blacks of B1 and C1. Then I connected A2 directly to the whites of B2 and C2. This DOES work—the thermostat did power on but the heaters were turning on and off every 3 seconds. I have since learned that CASA DOES NOT support fan-forced heaters :(

For anyone interested, I did find a smart line-voltage thermostat that does support fan-forced heater: https://getmysa.com/.